# Prove that a function is constant.

Tags: limits, analysis, functions

It is an open problem (still open) published on a Chinese mathematics magazine, but i am asking this just because i can not figure it out. I wonder if someone can help? I won't use any answers here to contact the editorial office of the magazine..

And here is the problem:

**Problem.** (Provider: Jiaqiang MEI, NJU) Suppose $f $ be a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$, and if for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{h^3} \int_{-h}^{h} f(x+t)t\ dt =0.
$$
Prove that $f$ is constant.

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: The limit holds when $f$ is constanct. The integral interval is symmetric and there is a $t$ after it. I have tried some ways but none of them were useful..

Comment: OMG! Yes! Thank you very much! Actually i have searched this problem but i didn't find it! I really appreciate it!  @Saad